# How to declare enums in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, enums

I'd like to declare some enums that should be globally accessed from anywhere in my application, eg:

```
enum AIState { Asleep, Idling, Chasing, Fleeing, HavingLunch };
```

Question: where and how do I have to declare those enums withint an `angularjs` app?

main.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.config(...);
```

I later want to access them using `AIState.Asleep`, so I could pass them as a parameter and delegate my logic accordingly.

Comment: Ok then what are recommended ways of declaring the enum inside?

Comment: Are you asking for a way to create a set of enum-like constants? JavaScript has no native enum facility.

Comment: Yes, probably I'm asking this... from the `java` point of view.

Answer (score 12):

use `constant`

```
angular
    .module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .constant("myConfig", {
        "key": "value"
    })
```

you can inject `constant` as dependency and can use it

```
myApp.controller('myButton', ['myConfig', function(myConfig) {
  var k = myConfig['key'];
});
```

Basically you can use `constant` or `value`.

some references

1. [Constant](http://twofuckingdevelopers.com/2014/06/angularjs-best-practices-001-constants/)
2. [Value](https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2014/01/14/angularjspart-9-values-and-constants/)

Comment: But how could I later access them via `AIState.Asleep`?

Comment: you can inject it as dependency  and can use it in any controller, directive, services etc

Comment: this is not enum, this is key-value pair, and I do not want to duplicate key and value